# how to insert "don't string into mysql table?

Tags: php, sql

i can i insert the keyword `don't` into my table using the `SQL` query below:

```
INSERT INTO feedback (user_id, user_type, problem, description, status,
posted_on) VALUES ('IN0018','MR','I don't have any prob','ha hah ha ha 
ha','1',NOW())
```

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements with bind variables, it eliminates all these sorts of problems.

Comment: prepared statements definitely is **the** way to go. otherwise, you are prone to lots of errors and security holes. while the answers currently given might all work, they are perfect examples of *how not to do it*

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the character. You can achieve it using:

```
INSERT INTO 
feedback (user_id, user_type, problem, description, status, posted_on)
 VALUES 
('IN0018','MR','I don''t have any prob','ha hah ha ha ha','1',NOW())
                     /
                    Here
```

use two single quotes to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Put another ' : `'I don''t have any prob'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$dt = "I don't have any prob";

$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback (user_id, user_type, problem, description, status, posted_on) VALUES ('IN0018','MR','$dt','ha hah ha ha ha','1',NOW());";
```

Try this solution.